# How this code snippet is working in I2C controller

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

I'm trying to understand the following code snippet from i2c-mpc.c I2C controller.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-mpc.c#L440

```
static int mpc_write(struct mpc_i2c *i2c, int target,
             const u8 *data, int length, int restart)
{

    int i, result;
    unsigned timeout = i2c->adap.timeout;
    u32 flags = restart ? CCR_RSTA : 0;

    /* Start as master */
    writeccr(i2c, CCR_MIEN | CCR_MEN | CCR_MSTA | CCR_MTX | flags);
    /* Write target byte */
    writeb((target << 1), i2c->base + MPC_I2C_DR);

    result = i2c_wait(i2c, timeout, 1);
    if (result < 0)
        return result;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        /* Write data byte */
        writeb(data[i], i2c->base + MPC_I2C_DR);

        result = i2c_wait(i2c, timeout, 1);
        if (result < 0)
            return result;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please point me out what exactly we are doing 440th line `writeccr(i2c, CCR_MIEN | CCR_MEN | CCR_MSTA | CCR_MTX | flags);`

Is it the all four register is getting setup to value 1 and what exactly flag varibales contains?

Comment: Please don't use '***' to identify the line with the problem - it gives contributors nightmares.

Comment: It's ORing four bits into flags and writing the result into control register. There should be an include file that identifies the 'CCR_MIEN' etc. bitmasks, and the controller user-manual should explain what each bit controls in the hardware.

Comment: For the register description: see the MPC107 PCI Bridge/Memory
Controller User’s Manual, page 408 http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MPC107UM.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to write unreadable and unmaintainable code (e.g. as often found in ucontroller code), then the statement in question could be written as:

```
if (restart)
    CCR = 0xF4;
else
    CCR = 0xF0;
```

But readable and maintainable code use symbolic names for each control bit (or field/option) in peripheral registers.
So for the CCR register, the driver defines these symbols at lines 45:50:

```
#define CCR_MEN 0x80
#define CCR_MIEN 0x40
#define CCR_MSTA 0x20
#define CCR_MTX 0x10
#define CCR_TXAK 0x08
#define CCR_RSTA 0x04
```

Standard practice is to use a mnemonic for the register as a prefix, and to reuse the hardware name (as found in the datasheet) for the rest of each control-bit name.
So the 2nd parameter in the function is a bitwise ORing of four constants and one variable that would produce either 0xF4 or 0xF0, depending on the value of passed argument **restart**.

---

Note that *NIX kernels (i.e. well-structured code) usually define memory-mapped peripheral registers as simple addresses and use a *function* (or macro) to perform the write (or read) operation, unlike the way that ucontroller code often uses an assignment statement.  This convention avoids overloading the register name so that address arithmetic can still be performed.
For example the driver defines a register offset for the Control Register

```
#define MPC_I2C_CR 0x08
```

and then the definition of **writeccr()** in the driver to write to the CCR register is

```
static inline void writeccr(struct mpc_i2c *i2c, u32 x)
{
    writeb(x, i2c->base + MPC_I2C_CR);
}
```

The **base** variable would contain the virtual address that the peripheral registers were mapped to using an **ioremap()** call with the physical address range.
Whereas ucontroller code would typically just dereference the (physical) address:

```
#define  CCR  (volatile u8 *)0x000003008
```

---

> what exactly flag varibales contains?

The declaration and initialization at line 437:

```
    u32 flags = restart ? CCR_RSTA : 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
u32 flags;
if (restart != 0) {
    flags = 0x04;    /* CCR_RSTA */
} else {
    flags = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sawdust for your detailed response on this,I would really like to know what would be the outcome of 440th line,is it to set the respected bit of all involved registers in one statement.

Comment: I've already answered that.  You need to read my answer again.  Line 440 will assign either 0xF4 or 0xF0, depending on the value of passed argument **restart**, to the Control Register.  There are no *"all involved registers"*, there's just the one **Control Register**.

Comment: Oh,sorry I didn't get it earlier and Thanks once again.